# My custom taxonomy is only displaying 1 of 3 terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy called Newsroom Categories and was able to get the first term to display using some array values, conditional statements, and foreach loops:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false, 'name' => 'newsroom_categories' );
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 

if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        $count = count($terms);

        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $termlinks = get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);                                                
            }
        }
    }
}?> 

<a href="<?php echo $termlinks;?>"><?php echo $term->name;?></a>
```

However no matter what term is selected in the page editor, only the first term is the only one that renders. How do I get more than the first term to display? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `foreach` loop you're overwriting the value of `$termlinks` before you ever output the previous one:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $termlinks = get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);                                                
}
```

All that code will do is ensure that `$termlinks` is set to the *last* term in the `$terms` array.

It also means that when you finally output `$term->name` it will be the name of the last `$term` in the loops.

If you want to output for each of the terms you need to move the output to inside the loop:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $termlinks . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';                                                
}
```